# How to install Ubuntu with /usr on a different partition than /?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I've done a bit of research and found lots of questions about either moving the `/usr` directory to another partition or installing Ubuntu with `/home` on a different partition but couldn't find anything about installing Ubuntu with `/usr` on the same HDD as `/home`.

I primarily use Ubuntu for work where I use Docker and other memory heavy applications for development. My setup consists of an SSD and an external HDD. My SSD is shared with my dual boot for Windows and I can only create a small partition that I'd like to use only for booting up Ubuntu, and have the rest of my files and applications on my external HDD.

I've installed Ubuntu before using my SSD partion to mount at `/` and my external HDD to mount at `/home`. But i also realized doing so leaves `/usr` (which gets very large) on my small SSD partition.

My thinking of solving this problem is:

1. Install Ubuntu again and enter the disk partitioning screen (after clicking "Something Else")
2. Mount `/` on my SSD like before
3. Partition my external HDD to mount at `/usr` and `/home` on different partitions of the same disk

Please let me know if this is possible or if mounting `/usr` on the same HDD as `/home` requires further steps

Comment: I'm installing Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What you describe sounds absolutely reasonable. I would recommend to prepare the partitions before installation using gparted and then just tell the installer which one to use for which mount point.